# Erro: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php

Estou aprendendo php e tenho o seguinte código cujo erro não consigo descobrir:

```
try{

    $_POST["imagem"] = "";
    if($bd->insert("AGENDA_agenda",$_POST) === true){

        $img = upaImagem();
        $idAgenda = $bd->insert_id;
        if($img == 0 || !$bd->query("update AGENDA_agenda set imagem='$img' where idAGENDA_agenda='$idAgenda'")){
            die("<script type='text/javascript'>
                alert('Evento Cadastrado!\\nMas é necessário reenviar a imagem!');
                window.parent.loadConteudo('agenda/agenda.php?acao=ed&idAGENDA_agenda=$idAgenda');
            </script>");
        }

        die("<script type='text/javascript'>
                alert('Evento Cadastrado!');
                window.parent.loadConteudo('agenda/agenda.php?acao=cad');
            </script>");
    }else{  
        $msgErro = $bd->erro();
        if(!empty($msgErro)){
            throw new Exception($bd->erro());
        }
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo "<div class='erro'>".$e->getMessage()."</div>";
}
```

Poderiam me ajudar? O erro é:

> ‘Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in F:\wamp\www\CM4K\adm\classes\class.bd.php on line 105:’

```
if($this->query($queryCompare)->num_rows > 0){
                $this->seterro("Nome Inválido!");
                return false;
            }
            return $this->query($sql);
```

Comment: Creio que não precise **comentar** que a **comunidade** é em **Português!**, ops já comentei!

Comment: Qual dessas linhas é a 105?

Comment: 105: if($this->query($queryCompare)->num_rows > 0){

Comment: 67: if($bd->insert("AGENDA_agenda",$_POST) === true){

Comment: Não seria `if($bd->query($queryCompare)->num_rows > 0)` e `return $bd->query($sql);`?

Comment: Resolvido, valeu!!